# What LDAP information could be persisted in my application?

Tags: .net, ldap, roles, roleprovider

Consider a classic LDAP usage for authentication and consequent calls to check if the user has rights to access an object accessible to groups "foo", "bar" and "baz".

I am wondering if I am allowed to persist exact role names, i.e. "foo", "bar" and "baz" and then make  `CurrentUser.IsInRole("Foo") || CurrentUser.IsInRole("Bar") || CurrentUser.IsInRole("Baz")` ? My answer is no since the role (group) name could be changed by the directory administrator at any time. But what to persist, an identifier of a kind?

I have stumbled upon a WebSphere configuration section at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v510/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wpf/wmm_map.html, the bottom line is that the identifier attribute is configured per provider type. Is this accurate and does it solve the above problem (renamed objects)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any directory admin that goes around changing role names needs his head examined frankly. You have to 'persist' *something,* not that 'persist' is really the correct term, and the CN is as good as anything else, much better than most. All the examples and samples I've ever seen used hard coded role names.

Comment: Seems fair and simplifies the external role handling and persistence a great deal but what if a department is merged with another one or something? This will lead to CN change. Or could this change be considered so drastical that my application's admins have to adapt to it and go change role names manually?

Comment: That just shows that you need to design your LDAP directory properly. You certainly shouldn't be using department names as role names, you should use strings that you *can* leave unchanged and hardwire into applications. I recommend you get a good book on the topic, there are several.

Comment: ok will do, although the target directory is not local, we need to deploy to an existing infrastructure that we have no control on...

Comment: Then either it has been correctly designed or it hasnt. If it hasn't there is no solution other than redoing it. Normally there is a separate subtree of Roles which is maintained completely separately from departments, divisions etc. And the role names are fixed so that applications can be written. If they are not fixed, applications cannot be written, it's as simple as that.